# Sub Totalling Relational Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have a datatable with relational data structure, I need to sum up the sub nodes to their parent nodes all the way up to the top parent (NULL parent Id)

I have attached 2 images which shows the original table and another with the expected results

[image: original data in datatable]

[image: expected results]

Cheers

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  The syntax varies, especially for more advanced queries like this one.

Comment: I would like to do it within a datatable as some of this data in not in the db yet.

Comment: add correct tags to your question, isn't it about C# and LINQ rather then SQL ?

Comment: Yes, I am new to stackoverflow and having bit of trouble getting around the interface, thanks for your help

Comment: You can do this farely easy from within certain databases (SQL server for one) but it really depends on what database system you're using. Please enlighten us

Comment: Te backend database is SQL Sever and the table structure is a per the images, ideally I would like to do this within a data table because some of the data does not exist in the db. However I would like to see how to achieve this in SQL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken an approach that simulates data as they could have been materialized from a database by some ORM, i.e. a class that contains data and a collection of children. Plus some "business logic" to calculate the required numbers. So you can choose a db approach as well as an in-memory approach.

In Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[]
    { 
        new Record { Id = 1, ParentId = null, Qty = 1, Cost = 0.0m },
        new Record { Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Qty = 2, Cost = 0.0m },
        new Record { Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Qty = 3, Cost = 0.0m },
        new Record { Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Qty = 4, Cost = 0.0m },
        new Record { Id = 5, ParentId = 3, Qty = 5, Cost = 0.0m },
        new Record { Id = 6, ParentId = 2, Qty = 6, Cost = 1.7m },
        new Record { Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Qty = 7, Cost = 1.8m },
        new Record { Id = 8, ParentId = 5, Qty = 8, Cost = 1.9m },
        new Record { Id = 9, ParentId = 5, Qty = 9, Cost = 2.0m },
    }.ToList();

    // Mimic ORM's job:
    data.ForEach(d => d.ChildRecords = 
        data.Where(c => c.ParentId == d.Id).ToList());

    data.Select(d => new { d.Id, d.Cost, d.TotalCost } ).Dump();
}

class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    private decimal _cost = 0m;
    public decimal Cost
    {
        get { return this._cost + this.ChildRecords.Sum(cr => cr.TotalCost); }
        set { this._cost = value; }
    }

    public decimal TotalCost
    { 
        get { return this.Qty * this.Cost; }
    }

    public ICollection<Record> ChildRecords;
}
```

Result:

```
Id  Cost    TotalCost
1   619.2   619.2
2   60.6    121.2
3   166     498
4   12.6    50.4
5   33.2    166
6   1.7     10.2
7   1.8     12.6
8   1.9     15.2
9   2       18
```

An optimization could be to apply some memoization, i.e. let the Cost property store the result of its getter in a private member variable.